# Nexus and Maven: Access to the Maven Central Repo?

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, nexus

I've got some trouble using Nexus and Maven.
When I try to build projects with Maven using the Nexus, Maven is not able to find any artifact. I added this to the Maven Settings:

```
     <mirror>
       <id>nexus</id>
       <url>http://localhost:6060/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
       <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
     </mirror>
```

to connect Maven with the Nexus.
The Maven central repo is also defined in the Nexus settings

Comment: What IDE are you using or are you going command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation of [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html) you should configure the settings.xml file like the following:

The most important thing is that *mirrorOf* contains only an single asterik to get all request redirected to the configured Nexus instance.

```
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
      <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
     <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this :

```
<mirror>
    <id>nexus-local</id>
    <url>http://localhost:6060/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    <mirrorOf>external:*</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
```