# Using Nexus repository instead of public Maven in Idea Intellij

Tags: maven, nexus

How can I force Idea Intellij to download from Nexus repository instead of Maven Public repo?
Where can I configure that in Idea properties?
It's not defined in `pom.xml` files and I'd prefer not to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nexus and Maven: Access to the Maven Central Repo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142763/nexus-and-maven-access-to-the-maven-central-repo)

Comment: I think that this is a maven problem, not an intellij problem. Your accepted answer attests to this. I've removed the intellij tag and voted to close this as its a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if it will work also on Idea Intellij ( I am using spring source studio - eclipse clon) , but should because maven configuration is in settings.xml in .M2 directory which is located in your home directory. Just use something like this ( my server is running on nexus-server:8081):

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <servers>
    <server> 
      <id>releases</id>
      <username>user-name</username>
      <password>your-password</password>
    </server>
    <server> 
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <username>user-name</username>
      <password>your-password</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
            <id>nexus</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <url>http://nexus-server:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <!--Disable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
            <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://central</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://central</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <!--make the profile active all the time -->
        <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```